# Get Text of an element error Android Jsoup

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I want to get text of a web element from structure like this :

```
        <td style="background-position: 0% 0%">
            <span>AAA</span>
        </td>
        <td style="background-position: 70% 0%">
            <span>1112</span>
        </td>
```

I want to get 1112 text, I have try this code :

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Element description = document.select("td > span:matchesOwn("+AAA+") + td > span").first();

desc= description.text();
```

but that always error, the logcat shows that this code error :

```
desc= description.text();
```

Anybody can help ?

Comment: logcat :
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.androidbegin.jsouptutorial.MainActivity$Description.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:118)

Comment: line 118 is :desc= description.text();

Comment: @hareesh145 have you ever got this problem before ?

Comment: doc.select("td > span:matchesOwn("+AAA+") + td > span") doesn't find any element that match the query and returns an empty element calling first() @Redturbo

Comment: finally I found the answer, thx @hareesh145 for the clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to get that, I use tree statement :

```
Elements td = document.select("span:matchesown("+AAA+")").parents();
org.jsoup.nodes.Element tdnext = td.first().nextElementSibling();
Elements span = tdnext.select("span");
desc= span.text();
```

First I try to find span with AAA text, then I find the parent.
After that I try to find next td sibling. Finally, select span in that td sibling.